# Formatting a cell value to "MMMM" using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that I need some assistance modifying.

```
Sub CopyDataBasedOnTimeRangeMonth()
Dim i, LastRow
Dim Cell As Range


LastRow = Sheets("OPA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:U500").ClearContents
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Sheets("OPA").Cells(i, "G").Value >= Range("U1") And Sheets("OPA").Cells(i, "G").Value < Range("AC1") Then
Sheets("OPA").Cells(i, "R").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

For the calculation of "G" I want to use the format of "MMMM" of the value being calculated. In an excel formula I can use something like Text("G12","MMMM") and then continue with the formula but I don't know how to modify the about code to just to use the Month only value of "G".

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: So do you want `if month>=range("u1")`?...month being the month in, `cell(i,"G")`

Comment: yes that is correct - I will like to calculate the month being in cell(i, "G")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see below the variant of your code, which has been updated using variant provided by `Davesexcel` (+1), and also some correction from my side, just to simplify readability:

1) absolute reference to `Range()` replaced to `[]` shorthand method;
2) removed `Destination:=` as excessive, also destination range replaced by row, because when you copy the row then destination shall be the row;
3) applied `with (object)` method;
4) added type of the variables, e.g. `i` replaced by `i&` (means `i as long`)

```
Sub CopyDataBasedOnTimeRangeMonth()
    Dim i&, LastRow&, Cl As Range
    LastRow = Sheets("OPA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet2").[A3:U500].ClearContents
    With Sheets("OPA")
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            If Month(.Cells(i, "G")) >= Month(.[U1]) And _
               Month(.Cells(i, "G")) < Month(.[AC1]) Then
                .Rows(i).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

tested, works fine.

source:

[image]

destination:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am also getting the same Run-time error - type mismatch with this code as well

Comment: I have tested the code, it works fine for me, so, to get understanding of the issue behind the error, you shall provide your data sample.

Comment: Thanks Vasily the code works - the cause for the mismatch that I was getting was due to a month formula I used in one of the columns

Answer (score 2):

It would be best to have [U1] as a date as well, then formatted as month

`If Month(Sheets("OPA").Cells(i, "G")) >= Month(Range("U1"))`

Comment: I modified the code as `Sub CopyDataBasedOnTimeRangeMonth()
Dim i, LastRow
Dim Cell As Range


LastRow = Sheets("OPA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:U500").ClearContents
For i = 2 To LastRow
If Month(Sheets("OPA").Cells(i, "G")) >= Month(Range("U1")) And Month(Sheets("OPA").Cells(i, "G")) < Month(Range("AC1")) Then
Sheets("OPA").Cells(i, "R").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next i
End Sub` and now I am getting Run-time error - type mismatch.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can edit your original question to add the new code, putting it in comments is hard to read

Comment: Thanks for the help Davesexcel - the cause for the mismatch was due to a month formula I used in one of the columns